# Wordpress cutting images size

Tags: images

I'm currently working on a page's banner , and after a while i've noticed that my images are with slight worst quality that i expected.

I was uploading the images with the 1920x1024 size, but after i checked admin dashboard i noticed they have been shrunk to 1024x575 ! 
Is there any reason why this happens ?
And is there anyway to prevent this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the original image or are you using one of the other image sizes such as `large` or `medium`? WP creates multiple copies of the image in various sizes, but it always keeps the original uploaded image file

Comment: Yes it was that :) found the error just now , thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the method you're using to display the banner is using a specific image size. Usually wordpress can use a defined (or not) image size to display a media item, but if you check the media item, you'll be able to see the original upload.

Can you provide some code where you're displaying the banner?

You should check out the [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/), [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) methods and also if you should change the method to display the image.

Comment: Yes, maybe thats that. I'm importing the image via `$multiPostThumbnails = MultiPostThumbnails::get_the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'banner-image', NULL,  'secondary-featured-thumbnail');
`  I need to change the arguments of the function probably.

Comment: Definetly. You're using the `banner-image` image size. Just define a new size using `add_image_size()` (note the crop parameters) and change the image size string in tge $multiPostThumbnais line. :)

Comment: Yes thanks a lot changed it to `full` ! Thanks man ! Marked as solution

Comment: Thanks, Pedro! :)